# Known issues for playing 3gp videos in the AVPlayer framework?

Tags: ios, swift

Are there any known issues with AVPlayer not playing a 3gp file on device? mp4 files play fine, but playing a 3gp file back from a URL on the device isn't happening.

Thanks!

If it matters I'm on iOS 9 Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayer or AVPlayerViewController can play only 3gp files that have audio and video streams that are supported by Apple.

For example, 3gp file can have AMR audio stream(Adaptive Multi-Rate, a format for speech) - which is not supported since iOS 4.3