# using avplayerkit issue while playing video black screen coming

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

hello i am new to swift and i am using `AVPlayerViewController` for plaing video from my url but issue is that i am not able to load video only black screen showing let me show my code

**Code**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewPlayer: UIView!
    var player: AVPlayer!
    var avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsQvAnCGxzY"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: self.url)

        player = AVPlayer(url: url!)

        avpController.player = player

        avpController.view.frame.size.height = viewPlayer.frame.size.height

        avpController.view.frame.size.width = viewPlayer.frame.size.width

        self.viewPlayer.addSubview(avpController.view)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

}
```

Please refer code given and tell me where i am done wrong so that i can able to play video Thanks In Advance

Comment: you unable to play the www.youtube.com  video on AVPlayerViewController , bz its play on iFrame format. use WKWebview or YTPlayerView

Comment: but if i play any other video then issue is same

Comment: can you add the sample

Comment: Yes Sure after that i  added this URL "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp" but still issue is same

Comment: Also read some answer and try to run in main queue with dipatchmain queue but it wasn't working

Comment: @Anbu.karthik have any suggestion for this?

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357721/known-issues-for-playing-3gp-videos-in-the-avplayer-framework

Comment: Oh Yes Thanks Its Use-full for Me Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Its problem of URL .
AVPlayer never supports YouTube video. It  supports mp4 format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a video in your ViewController, you have to use [AVPlayerLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer). You have to implement player controllers yourself.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // creating video url
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4") else {
        return
    }
    
    // create AVPlayer
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    
    // setup AVPlayerLayer
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    
    // start playing
    player.play()
}
```

Otherwise use **AVPlayerViewController**. Instead of using its view present the viewController itself.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // creating video url
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4") else {
        return
    }
    
    // setup AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    // presenting playerViewController only after the viewControllers view was added to a view hierarchy.
    
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}
```